# Sequence of Partial Sums for repeated decimal

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I have been trying to figure out an explicit formula for the sequence of partial sums of a repeating decimal. Take 0.09 repeating for example. Using the fact that it is a geometric series with r < 1, I know that the limit of the sequence of partial sum is 0.09/(1-0.01), or 1/11 by using the formula a/(1-r) where a is the first term, but I want to find an explicit formula for the sequence.

Comment: Velcome to our site!

Answer (score 1):

Writing the first $n$ terms as a finite geometric series:  $$9\sum_{i=1}^n .01^{i}=0.09\frac {1-.01^{n}}{1-.01}$$  Plugging in $n=3$ gives $0.090909$ as desired.

Comment: Thanks, it was helpful once I got to the section in the textbook where they derive the formula a/(1-r).